# Using a case statement to SELECT AS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a piece of code where I am joining two tables and selecting certain columns, one of the columns (NetMarkdown) is summed and I wish to select it into 3 different columns based on the value of a separate column (MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD). The code I have is as follow:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, MVNDR_PRTY_ID as 'MVNDR_PRTY_ID', sum(NetMarkdown)=(CASE MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD
WHEN 4 THEN as 'Code4' 
WHEN 23 THEN as 'Code 23'
ELSE as 'Code Other'
END), 
FSCL_WK_DESC INTO ##temp FROM
STRMKDN LEFT JOIN TimeHierarchy
ON CAL_PRD_END_DT=CAL_DT
group by ITEM_ID, MVNDR_PRTY_ID, FSCL_WK_DESC, MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD
```

I get an error in line 1 saying "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Am I approaching this completely wrong? What would be the correct way to approach this? Thanks for your help

Comment: That is a little bit confusing. Can you add example data and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do three separate sums:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, MVNDR_PRTY_ID as 'MVNDR_PRTY_ID',
    sum(CASE WHEN MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD = 4 THEN NetMarkdown END) as Code4,
    sum(CASE WHEN MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD = 23 THEN NetMarkdown END) as Code23,
    sum(CASE WHEN MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD != 4 and
                  MKUP_MKDN_RSN_CD != 23 THEN NetMarkdown END) as CodeOther,
FSCL_WK_DESC INTO ##temp FROM
STRMKDN LEFT JOIN TimeHierarchy
ON CAL_PRD_END_DT=CAL_DT
group by ITEM_ID, MVNDR_PRTY_ID, FSCL_WK_DESC
```

The problem with your existing code is that you're effectively trying to change which columns appear in the result set (i.e. imagine if *no* row had a reason code of 4) - which you can't do outside of dynamic SQL.

At the moment, this will produce `NULL`s if a particular reason code is never seen - if you want to avoid that, wrap the `SUM(...)`s up with `COALESCE(SUM(...),0)`